# Enable full object model intellisense for Excel

Tags: excel, office-js

How can I see the intellisense list for Excel in Visual Studio? For example, below I'm unable to find the `getColumn` property.
I'm already using the Beta CDN reference in my project (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js):

[image]

Edit: even `getColumn` is not listed, it works in my project, tough.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of var range
Use Excel.Range range = ctx.....